# Runtime error - where is the mistake in my code

Tags: python

My former problem (which is solved now) was:

As an input, I have a list of nonnegative whole numbers which are supposed to be the coefficients of a polynomial. But I also want to evaluate the polynomial for a certain number x.

For example:
If we have `L=[2,3,1]` as an input and `x=42` we get `2x^2+3x+1=3655`
What I want is for example:

```
>>>p=polynomial([2,3,1])
>>>p(O)
1 
>>>p(42)
>>>3655
```

The code is

```
def polynomial(coef):
 def poly(x):
    result = 0
    x_n = 1  
    for a in reversed(coef):
        result += a * x_n
        x_n *= x 
    return result
 return poly
```

What I wanted to do now is to find the inverse , that means the input the is a monotone polynomial and the positive whole number y and I want to find a whole number x such that p(x)=y, and x  should be only in [1,10**10], for example:

```
>>>p=polynomial([2,3,1])
>>>p(O)
1 
>>>p(42)
>>>3655
>>>invert(3655,p)
42
```

This is what I have so far, but what I get is a runtime error:

```
def polynomial(coef):
 def poly(x):
    result = 0
    xn = 1  
    for c in reversed(coef):
        result += c * xn
        xn *= x 
    return result
 return poly


def invert(y,p):

test=10**10

if p(2)>p(1):
    if p(test)>y:
        test=test//2 +(test%2)
        return invert(y,p)
    elif p(test)<y:
        test=test+(test//2)
        return invert(y,p)
    else:
        return test

if p(2)<p(1):
    if p(test)<y:
        test=test//2 +(test%2)
        return invert(y,p)
    elif p(test)>y:
        test=test+(test//2)
        return invert(y,p)
    else:
        return test
```

The error that occurs is

```
  ...
  File "poly.py", line 17, in invert
   return invert(y,p)
  File "poly.py", line 14, in invert
  if p(2)>p(1):
   File "poly.py", line 5, in poly
   for c in reversed(coef):
   RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a    Python object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the full traceback - but I suspect a too deep recursion.

Comment: the identation is not correct

Comment: Do you not set `test` to `10**10` as first step of every recursion? That way it will never get smaller/larger... Additionally your branching only ever ends with an *exact* match, which is hard to get for floating point numbers.

Comment: @StefanS Yes, as that is the biggest number "test" can be..what is the mistake? Yea I edited my post, the input and output are restricted to being positive whole numbers

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Why is the recursion "too deep" (what exactly does that mean?)

Comment: Add a `print(test)` statement somewhere in the function and you'll see what the problem is (unless I'm mistaken). Your function `invert` calls itself (recursion), but every time `invert` is called, `test` is set to `10**10`. It looks like a homework problem to me, so I don't just want to fix the code. A hint: you could carry the value of `test` over with every call of the function.

Comment: Oh.. I thought it changes the variable test after each recursion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the code myself now, limiting everything to the knowledge/skill I only have so far, and it works:

```
def polynomial(coef):
 def poly(x):
    result = 0
    x_n = 1  
    for a in reversed(coef):
        result += a * x_n
        x_n *= x 
    return result
 return poly

def invert(y,p):

 x=10**10

 while p(x)!=y:
    if p(x)>y:
        w=x
        x=x//2
    elif p(x)<y:
        x=(x+w)//2
    return x
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `invert` function recurses forever because you never modify the arguments that you pass to the next call. You do modify `test`, but that doesn't do you any good, since the inner call will have its own copy of `test`.

There are a few ways you could fix the issue. You could pass `test` as an argument to the `invert` function, with your initial value a default that will be used the first time:

```
def invert(y, p, test=10**10):
    # ...

    # later, when you recurse:
    test = test // 2      # or whatever
    return invert(y, p, test)    # pass on the modified test value
```

Another (probably better) approach would be to abandon recursion, and use a loop instead. A `while` loop seems like it would be appropriate here:

```
def invert(y, p):
    test = 10**10

    sign = (-1)**(p(2) < p(1))

    while True:
        if p(test) > y:
            test -= sign * (test // 2)
        elif p(test) < y:
            test += sign * (test // 2)
        else:
            return test    # this is the only case that returns
```

I've left the overall algorithm the same as what your original code does (just streamlined a bit). That algorithm may not be correct if your polynomial isn't strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. You should really compute the derivative of the polynomial at `test` to determine which direction to adjust in, but I'll leave that to you to figure out.

Comment: Oh and of course I mean strictly increasing or strictly decreasing as a constant function does not have an inverse function

Comment: There are lots of non-constant polynomials that are neither strictly increasing or decreasing. The one you give in your example, 2x^2+3x+1, defines a parabola, so its inverse will have two (or zero) solutions for most `y` values. Your algorithm only tests if it increases or decreases between the `x`-values `1` and `2`, but there's no guarantee it behaves the same way near any given `test` value.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty to fix the indention of the code you posted. **Please verify that the below code is actually what you have, regarding indentions** The following code does return your desired output..

```
def polynomial(coef):
    def poly(x):
        result = 0
        x_n = 1  
        for a in reversed(coef):
            result += a * x_n
            x_n *= x 
        return result
     return poly

def invert(y,p,test): # updated

    # test=10**10 # This was the problem

    # You reset 'test' for every recursive call
    # which means you will stand still without
    # any progress until the max num of allowed
    # recursive calls are reached.

    if p(2)>p(1):
        if p(test)>y:
            test=test//2 +(test%2)
            return invert(y,p,test) # updated
        elif p(test)<y:
            test=test+(test//2)
            return invert(y,p,test) # updated
        else:
            return test

    if p(2)<p(1):
        if p(test)<y:
            test=test//2 +(test%2)
            return invert(y,p,test) # updated
        elif p(test)>y:
            test=test+(test//2)
            return invert(y,p,test) # updated
        else:
            return test

p = polynomial([2,3,1])
t = 10**10
print(invert(3655,p,t))
```

Comment: Why should it be restricted to two arguments? If so, then go for @Blckknght solution. I voted it up.

Comment: To learn other techniques..not a reason to downvote my question.

Comment: Well I don't have enough rep to downvote anything so wasn't me. However, more importantly, did you get your problem solved? You should mark Blckknght's answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: Well it did help me as I abandoned myself from recursion, but still wrote a complete different code now.